# How to Chromecast Spotify?

Tags: chromecast, spotify, amazon-kindle

How can I Chromecasting Spotify from an Android device?

1. App Image or only sound.
2. With or without Internet connection.
3. Utilizing Downloaded tracks, when available.
4. With my device as mobile Hotspot?  I tried Screencast, but it wants a Wi-Fi connection.  (Youtube works OK).
5. What about a Kindle?  (Now I have a Samsung phone running as hotspot, and a Kindle Tablet - if I could use the Kindle, I would also circumvent the hotspot issue).

Can it perhaps be difficult to find support for Kindle and Spotify, because the Chromecast intended for selling stuff for Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is rooted, you can use BubbleUPnP (in the Play Store) as an Xposed module. Then you can cast the phones audio to your chromecast or TV via DLNA.

Comment: (Probably a bit outdated, as you can Chromecast with Spotify now)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Spoticast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nop.spoticast&hl=en) by [NOP Developments](https://plus.google.com/+NOPDev/posts). By setting Device Broadcast to True and logging into your Spotify account, it will allow you to push your Spotify content onto the TV.

Keep in mind that because of the Spotify API, this isn't a perfect method. Sometimes the connection will fail or there will be a slight delay, but it doesn't require root or anything special.